# How to fill a value field in a query with reshape?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in which a series of dates is created for each article, after which these tables are joined. I need to change the request so that in the price field the prices are filled in chronological order.

I mean, if for a certain article the price field is empty, then if the date is less than the date in the line with the first non-null price, the price field is filled with the first value found. If the price field is empty, but the date is later than the first line with a non-null price, then the price field is filled with the last value found.

There is my query:

```
WITH price_sequence AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        article,
        price,
        LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY article ORDER BY date) AS next_date
    FROM
        market.prices_history
    WHERE
        price_type_id = 'W23'
),
date_series AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            '2022-01-01',
            '2024-12-31',
            '1 day'::interval
        )::date AS date,
        article
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT article FROM market.prices_history WHERE article NOT IN ('1', '100-3519200')) AS articles
)
SELECT
    ds.date,
    ds.article,
    ps.price
FROM
    date_series ds
LEFT JOIN
    price_sequence ps ON ds.date = ps.date AND ds.article = ps.article
ORDER BY
    ds.article,
    ds.date
```

[image]

I tried different queries but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of window functions like `LEAD, LAG` like this

```
    WITH price_sequence AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        article,
        price,
        FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY article ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS first_non_null_price,
        LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY article ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_value_forward
    FROM
        market.prices_history
    WHERE
        price_type_id = 'W23'
        AND article NOT IN ('1', '100-3519200')
),
filled_prices AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        article,
        CASE
            WHEN price IS NOT NULL THEN price
            WHEN date < MIN(date) FILTER (WHERE price IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY article) THEN first_non_null_price
            ELSE last_value_forward
        END AS price
    FROM price_sequence
),
date_series AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            '2022-01-01',
            '2024-12-31',
            '1 day'::interval
        )::date AS date,
        article
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT article FROM market.prices_history WHERE article NOT IN ('1', '100-3519200')) AS articles
)
SELECT
    ds.date,
    ds.article,
    fp.price
FROM
    date_series ds
LEFT JOIN
    filled_prices fp ON ds.date = fp.date AND ds.article = fp.article
ORDER BY
    ds.article,
    ds.date;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems correct but filed "price" still not filled.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I update the answer with Adjusted Window Function for Last Valueand some 
Correct Filling Logic, check if that helps @SergeyBakaevRettley

Comment: price_sequence now works fine, but in result table,after join, price filed still not filled. Unfortunatley, it's not a solution. But I'm grateful to you, I'll finish the rest on M @TSCAmerica.com